Turning on error reporting on my controller makes my page not render properly and enter quirks mode
There's a code on my controller for error reporting and this code is:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

And then when I load the page, it only loads the main content but not the header and footer. And in Firefox it says "This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “”".
And when I tried to remove the error reporting code, the page renders properly with the header and footer on it.
Can someone help me know how to fix this? Thanks and will be much appreciated.

Maybe some errors are printed before the html tags start? Just a guess, since we didn't receive a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]

@ADyson the error reporting code is at the topmost part of my controller function

Yes, that's my point. Look at the rendered page in the browser, using the browser's View Source feature

Doesn't CI report errors/warnings on its own? Do you really need that code? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html#error-reporting

Sometimes, the error is not visible on the front end. Check the page's source code and see what shows up. There could be some strings with errors, warnings, or notifications. Good luck
